# What is the advantage of a using a "Zone Controller"?

Tags: heating, valve, boiler, hydronic

Looking at most pre-fab hydronic panels, the provide a Zone Controller. Initially I though they were used to stage the activation of the pump until after the valve was able to open but, looking at most / all of the valves, they have "end switches" that will only switch when the valve is all the way open. Is the Zone Controller just a convenience device, providing power for valves and labeled terminals to help keep wiring multiple zones in order?